# Binding/Triggering "Select all"-CheckBox ComboBoxItem in WPF

Tags: wpf, combobox, compositecollection

I'm trying to make a WPF CustomControl CheckComboBox with a "Select All" item in addition to a user defined list of items. When "Select All" is selected, all items in the list should be checked accordingly. How can I act to the "Select All" item being clicked? I have tried a lot of things, but the property "SelectAll" in the CheckComboBox.cs is never entered.

This is my current code.

Generic.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CheckComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CheckComboBox}">
                    <ComboBox SelectedItem="{TemplateBinding SelectedItem}"
                              SelectedValue="{TemplateBinding SelectedValue}"
                              SelectedValuePath="{TemplateBinding SelectedValuePath}"
                              DisplayMemberPath="{TemplateBinding DisplayMemberPath}"
                              IsTextSearchEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsTextSearchEnabled}"
                              ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}"
                              x:Name="InnerComboBox" >

                        <ComboBox.Resources>
                            <ResourceDictionary>
                                <CheckBox x:Key="allItem" Content="All" IsChecked="{Binding SelectAll, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                <CollectionViewSource x:Key="items" Source="{Binding ComboBoxItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            </ResourceDictionary>
                        </ComboBox.Resources>

                        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                            <CompositeCollection>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource allItem}}"/>
                                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource items}}" />
                            </CompositeCollection>
                        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>

                    </ComboBox>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Content="{Binding Text}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

CheckComboBox.cs

```
   public class CheckComboBox : ComboBox
    {
        public class CheckComboBoxItem
        {
            public CheckComboBoxItem(bool isSelected, string text)
            {
                IsSelected = isSelected;
                Text = text;
            }
            public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }

        static CheckComboBox()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CheckComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CheckComboBox)));
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ComboBoxItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ComboBoxItems", typeof (ObservableCollection<CheckComboBoxItem>), typeof (CheckComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<CheckComboBoxItem>)));

        public ObservableCollection<CheckComboBoxItem> ComboBoxItems
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<CheckComboBoxItem>) GetValue(ComboBoxItemsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ComboBoxItemsProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectAllProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectAll", typeof (bool), typeof (CheckComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

        public bool SelectAll
        {
            get { return (bool) GetValue(SelectAllProperty); }
            set
            {
                foreach (var item in ComboBoxItems)
                {
                    item.IsSelected = value;
                }
                SetValue(SelectAllProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Setting test data:

```
ObservableCollection<CheckComboBox.CheckComboBoxItem> checkComboBoxItems = new ObservableCollection<CheckComboBox.CheckComboBoxItem>();
checkComboBoxItems.Add(new CheckComboBox.CheckComboBoxItem(false, "Generation 0"));
checkComboBoxItems.Add(new CheckComboBox.CheckComboBoxItem(true, "Generation 1"));
checkComboBoxItems.Add(new CheckComboBox.CheckComboBoxItem(false, "Generation 2"));
checkComboBox1.ComboBoxItems = checkComboBoxItems;
```

**Edit:**
Replaced the *SelectAll* DependencyProperty in CheckComboBox.cs with the following code, but OnSelectAll is not entered. The SelectAll combobox does not trigger the binding for some reason.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectAllProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectAll",
                    typeof (bool),
                    typeof (CheckComboBox),
                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false,
                        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
                        new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSelectAll)));

private static void OnSelectAll(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckComboBox checkComboBox = (CheckComboBox)d;
    foreach (var item in checkComboBox.ComboBoxItems)
    {
        item.IsSelected = (bool) e.NewValue;
    }
}

public bool SelectAll
{
    get { return (bool) GetValue(SelectAllProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectAllProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: Don't touch the [Dependency Properties Back CLR Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx#back_dependency_properties) use a [PropertyChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx).

Comment: True that. However, the binding does not trigger the "SelectAll" property even though the ComboBoxItems binding works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out how to trigger the "SelectAll" property. Notice the:

```
<ComboBoxItem>
    <CheckBox ... />
</ComboBoxItem>
```

**Generic.xaml**

```
...
<ComboBox.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="items" Source="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ComboBox.Resources>

<ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    <CompositeCollection>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <CheckBox Content="All" IsChecked="{Binding SelectAll, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource items}}" />
    </CompositeCollection>
</ComboBox.ItemsSource>
...
```

**CheckComboBox.cs**

```
public class CheckComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public class CheckComboBoxItem : ModelBase
    {
        public CheckComboBoxItem(bool isSelected, string text)
        {
            IsSelected = isSelected;
            Text = text;
        }

        private bool _isSelected;
        public bool IsSelected 
        { 
            get { return _isSelected; }
            set { Set(() => IsSelected, ref _isSelected, value); }
        }

        private string _text;
        public string Text 
        { 
            get { return _text; }
            set { Set(() => Text, ref _text, value); }
        }
    }

    static CheckComboBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CheckComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CheckComboBox)));
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectAllProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectAll",
                                    typeof (bool),
                                    typeof (CheckComboBox),
                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false,
                                        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
                                        new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSelectAll)));

    private static void OnSelectAll(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckComboBox checkComboBox = (CheckComboBox)d;
        IEnumerable<CheckComboBoxItem> items = (IEnumerable<CheckComboBoxItem>) checkComboBox.ItemsSource;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            item.IsSelected = (bool) e.NewValue;
        }
    }

    public bool SelectAll
    {
        get { return (bool) GetValue(SelectAllProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectAllProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Now I just have to figure out how to automatically de-select the "Select All" check box when another item is de-selected.